Facing issue in getting name in signin with apple in flutter
I have used this function to register user using apple signin but it does not get user name from apple signin neither in initial registration nor in again signin. Any help would be appreciated.I am trying to get user name but unable to find a proper solution for this purpose. Can someone tell me how can I get user name when user initially registers or check above mentioned code if there is any issue. Thanks in advance.
sign_in_with_apple: ^5.0.0
firebase_auth: ^4.12.1

Future signInWithApple() async {
_hasError = false;
notifyListeners();
bool canAppleSignIn = await SignInWithApple.isAvailable();

if (canAppleSignIn == true) {
  // executing our authentication
  try {
    final credential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
      scopes: [
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
      ],
    );

    final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
      idToken: credential.identityToken,
    );
    final UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);

    if (userCredential.user?.displayName == null ||
        (userCredential.user?.displayName != null && userCredential.user!.displayName!.isEmpty)) {
      final fixDisplayNameFromApple = [
        credential.givenName ?? '',
        credential.familyName ?? '',
      ].join(' ').trim();
      await userCredential.user?.updateDisplayName(fixDisplayNameFromApple);
    }
    if (userCredential.user?.email == null ||
        (userCredential.user?.email != null && userCredential.user!.email!.isEmpty)) {
      await userCredential.user?.updateEmail(credential.email ?? '');
    }

    user = FireStoreUser(
        email: userCredential.user?.email,
        imageUrl: userCredential.user?.photoURL ?? "https://winaero.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/User-icon-256-blue.png",
        name: userCredential.user?.displayName,
        provider: "APPLE",
        uid: userCredential.user!.uid,
      );

    await saveDataToSharedPreferences();

    notifyListeners();
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    switch (e.code) {
      case "account-exists-with-different-credential":
        _errorCode =
            "You already have an account with us. Use correct provider";
        _hasError = true;
        notifyListeners();
        break;

      case "null":
        _errorCode = "Some unexpected error while trying to sign in";
        _hasError = true;
        notifyListeners();
        break;
      default:
        _errorCode = e.toString();
        _hasError = true;
        notifyListeners();
    }
  }
} else {
  _hasError = true;
  notifyListeners();
}
}


can you try this one?
open your setting in you iphone
then go to your apple id/ your profile
then go to sign-in & security
then go to sign in with apple
then select your app and then remove your apple sign from that app
and then try to reinstall your app and try to sign in again.
